# Laravel & React : Limit access to identified user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I'm creating my first application using **Laravel** and **React**. I followed a tutorial online, and I noticed that the authentification, unlike what I was used to with only Laravel, is using `localStorage` instead of `Auth::user`.

With the following line I can get the informations of the authentified user :

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
```

I can access the info of the logged user like this :

```
{user.id}{user.name}{user.email}
```

Now in my application, each profile belong to a user.

[image]

Using `react` and `react-routes`, to access a profile, the user need to provide `id` of the profile in the addition of the url, like this :

```
<Route path="/customize/:id?" component={Home} />
```

The current problem is that **any user can view any profil**. I want to limit the privilege to see/modify the profiles to ONLY those who are related to the profiles. So when the user is logged, he can only manage his own profiles, or perhaps the profiles that have the same `user_id` as his `id.`

My `login.js` handler :
**Full code** : http://collabedit.com/vfy3k

```
function onSignInHandler() {
    setState({ isLoading: true });

    const infos = {
        email: state.email,
        password: state.password,
    };

    axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", infos)
        .then((response) => {
            setState({ isLoading: false });
            if (response.data.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
                localStorage.setItem(
                    "userData",
                    JSON.stringify(response.data.data)
                );
                setState({
                    msg: response.data.message,
                    redirect: true,
                });
            }
            if (
                response.data.status === "failed" &&
                response.data.success === undefined
            ) {
                setState({
                    errMsgEmail: response.data.validation_error.email,
                    errMsgPwd: response.data.validation_error.password,
                });
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setState({ errMsgEmail: "", errMsgPwd: "" });
                }, 2000);
            } else if (
                response.data.status === "failed" &&
                response.data.success === false
            ) {
                setState({
                    errMsg: response.data.message,
                });
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setState({ errMsg: "" });
                }, 2000);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: When you sign in you need to provide a username and password and then the local storage stores the details of the user who signed in. There's no way the local storage will know about any other users (based on the code you shared) unless you're blindly sending the user information when requested

Comment: @apokryfos That's what I meant. The infos of the logged user are stores then localstorage tech the data. When the user is logged, I want to give him access to only his profiles. He can't view other profiles whose `user_id` are different than his `id`

Comment: if the local storage only stores the logged in user data and you only read user data from the local storage how will a user read the data of other users?

Comment: @apokryfos A user is logged, right? If he sets in the url for example `localhost:8000/profile/1` , as his `user_id` is 1, he will see his profile. But if he sets `localhost:8000/profile/2`, he will see the profile of another user, which I would not want.

Comment: How will they see that profile? They can't directly access the database can they?

Comment: @apokryfos No they can't access to the database. I just told you how they can see a profile which isn't theirs, by setting an `id` on the url like this `localhost:8000/profile/2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232038/discussion-between-alyakra-and-apokryfos).